# MongoDB/Mongoose geoNear returns incorrect distance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, distance

When I attempt to find a document with defined geo coordinates using the geoNear() method, MongoDB's calculation of the distance appears to be off, resulting in an empty array of results.

I have the following document in my locations collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e4791244ea3215c8537425"),
    "name" : "Cool Place",
    "address" : "224 West 71th Street, New York, NY 10023",
    "rating" : 5,
    "facilities" : [...etc...],
    "coords" : [
        -73.983342,
        40.778183
    ],
    "openingTimes" : [...etc...],
    "reviews" : [...etc...]
}
```

My schema looks like this:

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: String,
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    'default': 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 5
  },
  facilities: [String],
  coords: {
    type: [Number],
    index: '2dsphere'
  },
  openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
  reviews: [reviewSchema]
});
```

The relevant parts of my controller look like this:

```
var theEarth = (function () {
  var earthRadius = 6371; // km, miles is 3959

  var getDistanceFromRads = function (rads) {
    return parseFloat(rads * earthRadius);
  };

  var getRadsFromDistance = function (distance) {
    return parseFloat(distance / earthRadius);
  };

  return {
    getDistanceFromRads: getDistanceFromRads,
    getRadsFromDistance: getRadsFromDistance
  };
})();

var buildResultsList = function (results) {
  var resultsList = [];

  results.forEach(function (doc) {
    resultsList.push({
      distance: theEarth.getDistanceFromRads(doc.dis),
      name: doc.obj.name,
      address: doc.obj.address,
      rating: doc.obj.rating,
      facilities: doc.obj.facilities,
      coords: doc.obj.coords,
      _id: doc.obj._id
    });
  });

  return resultsList;
};

module.exports.locationsListByDistance = function (req, res) {
  var lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);
  var lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
  var maxDistance = parseFloat(req.query.maxDistance);

  var point = {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [lng, lat]
  };

  var geoOptions = {
    spherical: true,
    maxDistance: theEarth.getRadsFromDistance(maxDistance),
    num: 10
  };

  Loc.geoNear(point, geoOptions, function (err, results, stats) {
    sendJsonResponse(res, 200, buildResultsList(results));
  });
};
```

Finally, this is the request that I'm making:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/locations?lng=-73.9827568&lat=40.7791425&maxDistance=10
```

However, I am only getting an empty array of results, even though the location is within 10km of the coordinates I specified in my request. If I change the `maxDistance` query param to 100000, the result is returned, showing a distance of 749557.1657218104 km:

```
[{"distance":749557.1657218104,"name":"Cool Place","address":"224 West 71th Street, New York, NY 10023","rating":5,"facilities":["Hot drinks","Premium wifi"],"coords":[-73.983342,40.778183],"_id":"56e4791244ea3215c8537425"}]
```

I used http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html to calculate the distance between these two sets of coordinates, and saw that they are only 0.1175 km apart.

Another note: if I use the exact coordinates associated with the location (-73.983342, 40.778183) in my query, the location IS returned, with the correct distance of 0 km.

Successful request:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/locations?lng=-73.983342&lat=40.778183&maxDistance=10
```

Returns:

```
[{"distance":0,"name":"Cool Place","address":"224 West 71th Street, New York, NY 10023","rating":5,"facilities":["Hot drinks","Premium wifi"],"_id":"56e4791244ea3215c8537425"}]
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Mongoose do you use? Try to use "mongoose": "~3.8.20" and update the npm package and try again.